# spring4.0 Context initialization failed hasAnnotation

Tags: spring, maven, nosuchmethoderror

spring mvc initialization failed, the stacktrace is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.isHandler(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    ... 21 more
```

the pox.xml:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.1</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.mqtt-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>mqtt-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.hawtdispatch</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawtdispatch</artifactId>
        <version>1.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.hawtdispatch</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawtdispatch-transport</artifactId>
        <version>1.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource.hawtbuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawtbuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
        <artifactId>msgpack-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.msgpack</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-msgpack</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
    <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

maven-dependency:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ databus ---
[INFO] com.ckxh.cloud.iot:databus:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- com.ckxh.cloud:base:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.fusesource.mqtt-client:mqtt-client:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch:jar:1.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch-transport:jar:1.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.msgpack:msgpack-core:jar:0.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.msgpack:jackson-dataformat-msgpack:jar:0.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.ckxh.cloud:persistence:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:6.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.influxdb:influxdb-java:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

i check all the dependency and Looks quite right。the error shows "NoSuchMethodError --hasAnnotation" ,but when i debug the code and found this method is there，this driving me mad for days，needs help...